# 'No such Column' error when using SELECT on a view

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

```
CREATE VIEW [0_NumOfCode] AS
    SELECT tbDeviceId.deviceId,
           count(DISTINCT tbCodeList_AV.codeNum) AS NumCode
      FROM tbDeviceId
           INNER JOIN
           tbCodeList_AV ON tbDeviceId.deviceId = tbCodeList_AV.deviceId
     GROUP BY tbDeviceId.deviceID
    UNION
    SELECT tbDeviceId.deviceID,
           count(DISTINCT tbCodelist_AC.codeNum) 
      FROM tbDeviceId
           INNER JOIN
           tbCodelist_AC ON tbDeviceId.deviceId = tbCodelist_AC.deviceId
     GROUP BY tbDeviceId.DeviceID;
```

Context: I'm actually creating a C++ program that uses SQLite and takes in input of a .db file, so this SQL code that I've given here(which is from the db file) is not mine and I don't think I should (or should have to) change it, but I'm facing a perplexing problem, which is why I'm asking this question.

Basically, now I want to SELECT the deviceId column of this 0_NumOfCode view, but how do I do that? 
Neither

```
SELECT tbDeviceId.deviceId FROM [0_NumOfCode]
```

nor

```
SELECT deviceId FROM [0_NumofCode]
```

nor

```
SELECT [0_NumOfCode].deviceId FROM [0_NumOfCode]
```

did the job (The 'No such column' error). However, when I select *, the column and the data does show up under tbDeviceId.deviceID

Now, I *THINK* an alias for the column might solve the problem, but like I said, I don't think I should change the SQL code. So

1) Given this SQL code, how do I do this?

2) (for my own curiosity) An alias would have solved it too, right?

**UPDATE :** My initial questions have been solved (in the comments), although I'm still kinda lost on how it works(' vs ` vs no quotes).

Also, a new problem I face:

```
SELECT tbdeviceid.DeviceID,
       numcode,
       numbrand,
       devicename15,
       devicename30,
       comment,
       devicenameCN
  FROM tbdeviceid
       INNER JOIN
       [0_NumofBrand] ON tbdeviceid.deviceId = [0_NumofBrand].deviceId
       INNER JOIN
       [0_numofcode] ON tbdeviceid.deviceId = [0_numofcode].deviceId
```

The last line gives the no such column error. How do I represent the column?

Comment: maybe SELECT \`tbDeviceId.deviceId\` FROM [0_NumOfCode] ?

Comment: And also an alias would solved it, just test with `select NumCode from 0_NumOfCode`

Comment: It might be possible that the column "DeviceId" is no longer with the table tbDeviceId. Verify it by "select * from tbDeviceId".

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot @amow :D 
(BTW, I tried ' instead of ` the first time and it didn't work, what's the difference between them?)

Comment: Also, yes, the alias would solve it too, I tested.

Comment: @svm96 I guess the content between `'` will be treated as a plain text

Comment: @amow I see. Any suggestions for the new question I asked in the update?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this would work..
Modify your view with alias.

```
SELECT tbDeviceId.deviceId as dId, ...
```

Then use the select statement using that alias

```
Select dId from [0_NumOfCode]
```

Comment: Indeed, an alias does solve it, but like I said in the question, the SQL code is not mine and I preferred a solution that didn't modify it

Comment: My ideas is: Then you should Insert (all)  into a temp table from view, then drop the 'NumCode' column from temp table. Then you can use the `Select * from temp`.

Comment: I guess that would work, but that (in my opinion) is rather unnecessarily long, especially compared to the solution @amow gave me in the comments. My question has been solved, but since his is a comment, there's no accept button on it. I have asked a follow-up question though, maybe you can explain that?